# MySQL Workbench: Why is the default VARCHAR (45)?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I start design my database on paper, I usually set the varchar length to 32, 64, 128, 256, etc.

But when I started to work on MySQL Workbench 5.2ce, I noticed every time I set a field's type to varchar, the form would set its size to 45 by default.

*Is this a recommended value?*

Maybe historically, 45 is the most used size for the `varchar` type. If so, then why 45? Why not 48 or 47 (maybe it needs an extra word to save something I guess)?

I don't get it. Maybe I should set the field type to `varchar(29)` for storing a string with a length of 20 characters?

I did a search I found many ppl set their length to 255 (not 256). Would this be a serious problem?

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this! It seems like an arbitrary number, making all VARCHARs 45 by default.

Comment: I'm using Workbench 6.3.2.0 and when I create a varchar it just prompts me for the length. It does not assume 45. There is no magic about the value 45.

Comment: varchar(255) is a common choice because it used to be the maximum varchar length before MySQL 5.0. Internally, varchar(255) needs only one byte to store the length of a given string. Once you go to varchar(256) or more, it requires two bytes per varchar to store the length.

Comment: I recommend you simply choose the length that will fit all the strings you need to store in that column.